# How to declare Typescript type that is AnyRecord OR an object array?

Tags: typescript

In short, I want to do this:

```
interface Rec {
  key: string;
}

type RecordOrList = Record<string, any> | Rec[];
```

So, `RecordOrList` is either some object, or a list of specific objects.

However, typescript here seems to treat arrays of `Rec`-s as Any Records. For example, this is valid code, but I was expecting it to be a type error ("int instead of string").

```
const x: RecordOrList = [{
  key: 123,
}];
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQcg3gWAFDLIDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gNz4C+++YpADiuggPZQAJgHkoAGWA1kAXjQZBQgDw06IegBpkcEKQB8yAD7yEAbQC6zPPgEhpAD0p9FYydLmncBYmUoBGACYAZg1WSyA

How can I make the code above type checked?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having here is that arrays *themselves* are - surprisingly - a valid `Record<string, any>` (specifically, it's a `Record<"length", number>`).

```
// Valid. WTF?
const x : Record<string, any> = [];
const a : keyof [] = "length"; // Valid
const b : keyof [] = "bogus";  // Invalid
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x); // => ["length"]
```

Instead of `any`, you could use `unknown` here:

```
interface Rec {
  key: string;
}

type RecordOrList = Record<string, unknown> | Rec[];

// Type error as expected
const x: RecordOrList = [{
  key: 123,
}];

// Works just fine
const y: RecordOrList = {key: 123}
const z: RecordOrList = [{
  key: "123",
}];
```

Or just narrow your Record value type to a list of scalar types.

Comment: Yeah. I figured out about `Record<string, unknown>`. But that type is super inconvenient, as it doesn't allow "normal" objects to be passed ("missing index signature"). Hoping for a different solution :)

Comment: Oh and in my actual code, I fixed the specific problem (not exactly the simplified version from the question) by using a generic that extends from `Record<string, any>`. Then later doing a conditional check. But I can't figure out how to generalize it into a solution here.